# while searching in a sorted 2d array on leetcode error arising in accordance to where i update variable element and i cant understand why?

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures, binary-search

question : Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a value target in an m x n integer matrix matrix. This matrix has the following properties:

Integers in each row are sorted in ascending from left to right.
Integers in each column are sorted in ascending from top to bottom.

Ans :  the solution given is correct but when element variable is updated at different location it gives error and I can't understand why?

```
class Solution {
public:
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
    int trow = matrix.size();
    int tcol = matrix[0].size();

    int rowIndex = 0;
    int colIndex = tcol - 1;
    
    int element = matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]; // already defined here
    while(rowIndex < trow && colIndex >= 0){
        element = matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]; // works here
        if(element == target){
            return 1;
        }
        if(element > target){
            colIndex --;
        }
        if(element < target){
            rowIndex ++;
        }
       // element = matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]; // this gives error here
    }
    return 0;
}
};
```

Comment: as element is already defined outside while loop updating it after all conditions are checked should be fine but gives error in leetcode.

Comment: The second position is *after* the indices are updated. Are they still in bounds? BTW, have you already studied the binary search algorithm?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with `main` function, hardcoded input data and expected output?

Comment: Have you stepped through an example where `target` is not within your matrix? Try `matrix=[[1]]`, `target=2`. What's the state on the line that gives an error?

Comment: Looks like you are not learning c++ from a good source. Good sources to learn cpp from are : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
 For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: *"it gives error"* -- what's the error? Compile-time? Run-time? Is there a message? For a runtime error: at which line, and what are the values of the variables used in that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when element variable is updated at different location it gives error and I can't understand why?

Your `while` loop condition ensures that at the start of the loop body, the indices `rowIndex` and `colIndex` are within the array bounds.

However, during the execution of the loop's body, one of these variables is updated with either `colIndex--;` or `rowIndex++;`. Once that has happened you cannot be sure the updated value is still within bounds, and so it is unsafe to use them at the end of the loop body to access `matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]`. First the loop condition should be verified, and only if it is true, it is safe again to access `matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]`.

If you access it at the end of the loop's body, it will go wrong when the matrix does not have the target value.

The most simple example is an array with just one row and column (so `trow` and `tcol` are both 1). Let's say `matrix[0][0]` is 10, and the target value is 5. Then the loop will start with `rowIndex` and `colIndex` both equal to 0. `element` will be 10. The comparison `element > target` is true, so `colIndex` is updated to become -1. Now it would be wrong to access `matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]` as -1 is not a valid index. Instead the `while` condition should be evaluated first, which would be false, and the function would return 0 (i.e., target was not found).

That's why the retrieval of `matrix[rowIndex][colIndex]` needs to happen at the top of the loop body and not at the bottom of it.

Comment: Thanks , that was pretty sufficient explanation ☺️